# how to mount chroot /proc on ubuntu start

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, mount, chroot

In order to run java inside chroot environment I have to mount /proc file system using the following command

```
mount -t proc none /proc
```

inside the chroot environment
or

```
mount -o bind /proc /path/to/chroot/proc
```

from outside
That's works well, but for me, I should mout /proc on each restart for the system.
How do I resolve it so I have /proc always mounted or even mount /proc on each start of the system
In a case that would be not secure or reliable, I'd solve my problem in another way if I know how to check if /proc is mounted or not using bash scripts!

Comment: Take a look at `fstab`

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @andlrc,
this has solved the problem using the fstab:
hope someone get used of it
fstab or file system table is used by the system to get information about partitions to automatically mount when run
used:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

to open it
added the following to make the system automatically mount the /proc

```
/path/to/chroot/proc /proc auto -o,bind 0 1
```

where that refers to -in order-:
1- the file system to mount
2- the mounting target
3- file system type .. auto to auto detect
4- mount options separated by ","
5- flag to enable/disable backup 
6- the order to check the partition for errors while booting 
hope this would be useful